# Ansible dnf module enable Fedora Copr repository

Tags: ansible, fedora, lxd, dnf, copr

I want to enable a Fedora Copr repository with Ansible. More specifically I want to convert this command:

```
dnf copr enable ganto/lxd
```

Using an Ansible `command` module I overcome this problem but break the task's idempotence (if run again, the role should not make any changes) (`changed_when: false` is not an option).

```
- name: Enable Fedora Copr for LXD
  command: "dnf copr enable -y ganto/lxd"
```

Also, I tried this:

```
- name: Install LXD
  dnf:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
    enablerepo: "xxx"
  with_items:
    - lxd
    - lxd-client
```

Where I test many variations for the option `enablerepo` without any success.

Is that possible using the [dnf](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dnf_module.html) Ansible module (or something else)?

Comment: dnf module should be idempotent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now possible thanks to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/copr_module.html

The original snippet using `command`

```yaml
- name: Enable Fedora Copr for LXD
  command: "dnf copr enable -y ganto/lxd"
```

can be changed to

```yaml
- name: Enable Fedora Copr for LXD
  community.general.copr:
    name: ganto/lxd
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `creates` to make your command idempotent; if the `.repo` file already exists then the task won't run:

```
- name: Enable Fedora Copr for LXD
  command:
      cmd: dnf copr enable -y ganto/lxd
      creates: /etc/yum.repos.d/_copr_ganto-lxd.repo
```

(You'd have to check that `enabled=1` manually)

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/_copr_ganto-lxd.repo

[ganto-lxd]
name=Copr repo for lxd owned by ganto
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/ganto/lxd/fedora-$releasever-$basearch/
type=rpm-md
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/ganto/lxd/pubkey.gpg
repo_gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Comment: @Dzintars there was a syntax error, I've fixed it (cf. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, the Ansible dnf module doesn't support enabling Copr repositories.

You can add a task that tests if your Copr repository is already enabled that guards the Copr enable task.

Example:

```
  shell:
      cmd: |
          dnf -C repolist enabled -v  | grep '^Repo-id' | awk '$3 == "copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:ganto:lxd" {print "enabled"}'
      warn: no
  check_mode: no
  changed_when: false
  register: lxd_copr

- name: Enable Fedora Copr for LXD
  command:
      cmd: dnf -y copr enable ganto/lxd
      warn: no
  when: lxd_copr.stdout == ''
```

Notes:

- double check the id of your copr repository as it's different from the short name you use to enable it
- I set `warn: no` because ansible warns about all `dnf` commands (because it suggests to use the dnf module, if possible)
- I set `check_mode: no` since it's safe to execute it even in `--check` mode
- I set `changed_when: false` because the command doesn't change system state

---

Alternatively you can add and enable a Copr repository with the [`yum_repository` Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html).

Example:

```
- name: enable copr
  yum_repository:
      name: "copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:{{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }}"
      file: "_copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:{{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }}"
      description: "{{ item[2] }}"
      baseurl: "{{ copr_url }}/results/{{ item[0] }}/{{ item[1] }}/fedora-$releasever-$basearch/"
      gpgkey: "{{ copr_url }}/results/{{ item[0] }}/{{ item[1] }}/pubkey.gpg"
      gpgcheck: yes
      enabled: yes
      skip_if_unavailable: yes
  vars:
      #copr_url: https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org
      copr_url: https://download.copr.fedorainfracloud.org
  loop:
      - [ganto, lxd, "Copr repo for LXD"]
```

This approximates the effect of the `dnf copr enable ganto/lxd` call. But there are some minor textual differences in the resulting `.repo` file (e.g. `True` vs. `1`, keys with default values missing) that would lead to this task reporting changed if e.g. the repository was already enabled with `dnf copr`.

Also, this arguably has a higher maintenance overhead as one would have to track changes Copr introduces to its `.repo` files.